# Discrete Math - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> How many five-card poker hands using 52 cards contain exactly two aces?

I know the answer is $$\binom{4}{2}\cdot \binom{48}3,$$ but I'm not sure how to explain it.

Any help here?

Answer (score 5):

There are $52$ two cards, $4$ aces and $48$ other non-ace cards. When you are choosing a hand with $2$ aces, there are $C(4,2)$ ways to choose the two aces and $C(48,3)$ ways to choose the other cards.

Comment: To add to this, the reason these terms are multiplied together to get the final answer is that there are $C(48,3)$ ways to choose the other cards for each of the $C(4,2)$ ways to choose the aces.

Comment: .... sometimes referred to as the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)

Comment: @amWhy cool! I never knew it had a name

Answer (score 3):

You are choosing two of the four aces and three of the remaining $48$ cards.  The choices are independent.